# Add multiple LSTM layers in tflearn

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, tflearn

How do I add another LSTM layer for following neural network?

```
net = tflearn.input_data([None, width, height])
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128 )
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, classes, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=learning_rate, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=3,tensorboard_dir='log')
```

`

Comment: add `net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128 )` between lstm and fully_connected layers

Answer (score 1):

```
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, return_seq=True)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 256)
```

Don't forget to set `return_seq=True` on your previous LSTM layer or you will get an error